# VBA Excel Variable Sorting on Multiple Keys/Orders

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

How can I sort on multiple columns (keys/orders) at the same time? When I run my below code it re-sorts the data when executing each line instead of one sort with multiple columns in the sort. Changing the 'key' or 'order' number from 1 to 2, etc. does not help. Thanks.

```
wsLast_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A3:BZ" & wsLast_Row).Sort key1:=Range("A3:A" & wsLast_Row), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
Range("A3:BZ" & wsLast_Row).Sort key1:=Range("B3:B" & wsLast_Row), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
Range("A3:BZ" & wsLast_Row).Sort key1:=Range("C3:C" & wsLast_Row), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
Range("A3:BZ" & wsLast_Row).Sort key1:=Range("D3:D" & wsLast_Row), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
Range("A3:BZ" & wsLast_Row).Sort key1:=Range("F3:F" & wsLast_Row), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Sub sdad()
    wsLast_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3:A" & wsLast_Row), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3:B" & wsLast_Row), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C3:C" & wsLast_Row), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D3:D" & wsLast_Row), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range("A3:BZ" & wsLast_Row)
        .Header = xlNo
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I copied your code into my sub and received an error box reading 'Compile error: Named argument not found'    'key4:=' is highlighted.

Comment: Never knew that VBA was limited to 3 keys. See revised answer

Comment: Works perfectly as intended, ty @Abe Gold

Comment: I ran into the 3-key limitation today and this worked a treat. Thank you Abe Gold!