# VBA Sorting 4 columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to sort **4** columns for my VBA application but it gives me a error like this

> "Application defined or object defined error"

this is my source code

```
Range("A3:X" & lastRow).Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("e3"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
               Key2:=Range("D3"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
               Key3:=Range("c3"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
               Key4:=Range("f3"), Order4:=xlAscending, _
               Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
               DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal
```

this is working without the Key4 and Order4 
I wonder what is wrong with my codes

Comment: The `Range.Sort` method only defines three keys (columns).

Comment: hmm do you have any suggestion ? for my concern sir @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Your question reads about sorting on **3** columns, so why do you need 4 keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel Variable Sorting on Multiple Keys/Orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998154/vba-excel-variable-sorting-on-multiple-keys-orders)

Answer (score 4):

I think this will give you what you're after:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Sort ' set this to the relevant book and sheet

    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C3"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F3"), Order:=xlAscending

    .SetRange Range("A3:X" & lastRow)
    .Apply

End With
```