# Named argument not found VBA compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a code to sort data in an Excel sheet that has 14 columns and every column I am considering as a Key.

When I try to run the following VBA code, I am getting `Compile error: Named argument not found`.

```
Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    .Sort Key1:=Range("O2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("P2"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("Q2"), Order3:=xlAscending,
    Key4:=Range("R2"), Order4:=xlAscending, Key5:=Range("S2"), Order5:=xlAscending, Key6:=Range("T2"), Order6:=xlAscending,
    Key7:=Range("U2"), Order7:=xlAscending, Key8:=Range("V2"), Order8:=xlAscending, Key9:=Range("W2"), Order9:=xlAscending,
    Key10:=Range("X2"), Order10:=xlAscending, Key11:=Range("Y2"), Order11:=xlAscending, Key12:=Range("Z2"), Order12:=xlAscending,
    Key13:=Range("AA2"), Order13:=xlAscending, Key14:=Range("AB2"), Order14:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Concatenate your sort key into one column, sort by that column?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of the [Range.Sort method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) there do only exist 3 `Key`, `Order` and `DataOption` parameter not 14.

> ```
> .Sort (Key1, Order1, Key2, Type, Order2, Key3, Order3, Header, OrderCustom, MatchCase, Orientation, SortMethod, DataOption1, DataOption2, DataOption3)
> ```

You need to change it to use `.SortFields`

```
With Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("O2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("P2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    'and so on … add your other fields here
    .Header = xlNo
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Sort is limited to 3 keys. Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998154/vba-excel-variable-sorting-on-multiple-keys-orders

Comment: @cekar no with this method it works with more than 3